# If a is odd, how do I prove that 3a is also odd?

Tags: logic

I know that if something is odd then $\exists k \in \mathbb{Z}: a = 2k + 1$. But what I get is:

$n = 2k + 1$

$3n = 3(2k+1)$

$3n = 6k + 3 $

But i can't factor 6k + 3 to give me 2k + 1 !

Any suggestions?

Comment: $6k+3=2*3k+2+1 =2(3k+1)+1$

Answer (score -1):

If you factor out a 3, $(6k+3)$ $=$ $3(2k +1) = 2(3k + 1) + 1.$ This is now an odd number. You are here in your post, try thinking about taking an odd number and multiplying it by 3. You get an odd number in any example you try. This is because an odd integer multiplied by an odd integer is always odd, the proof of this is another good exercise.

Comment: How do you know odd times an odd is odd if you don't prove it first?  If someone asks how to prove something answering "because it's always true" is not an acceptable answer.

Comment: That's why I added in my answer the proof of this fact is a good exercise, if this problem can be done the more general case is a further extension that would be good to attempt the proof of.